# Can you get the connection data from a mysqli object?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When you create a `mysqli` object in php, you feed it data so that it can connect. An example:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($address, $user, $pass, $database);
```

Is it possible to get the data you gave it back out of the resulting object?

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: why did you want that? var_dump($mysqli) explains you the instance ...

Comment: I don't need it. I'm asking because I'm curious.

Comment: Simple answer. No. Once the connection is made you cannot pull the credentials from the connection.

Comment: I don't know but just wondering, did you try var_dump connection object, what does that contain?

Comment: Just the ip, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

The data simply does not exist after it is used to begin the connection. Here's the output of `print_r`:

```
mysqli Object
(
    [affected_rows] => 0
    [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: [not sure if this was sensitive information, so redacted. was just a long string of numbers] $
    [client_version] => 50011
    [connect_errno] => 0
    [connect_error] => 
    [errno] => 0
    [error] => 
    [error_list] => Array
        (
        )

    [field_count] => 0
    [host_info] => localhost via TCP/IP
    [info] => 
    [insert_id] => 0
    [server_info] => 5.5.36
    [server_version] => 50536
    [stat] => Uptime: 294546  Threads: 1  Questions: 351  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 53  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 0  Queries per second avg: 0.001
    [sqlstate] => 00000
    [protocol_version] => 10
    [thread_id] => 99
    [warning_count] => 0
)
```